# How to avoid setState in useEffect in React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a simple `calculator` and calculate all values if any of them changed.

but I faced to a problem of `infinite loop`. I know it's caused by `setState` and trigger `useEffect` and then setState again.

So how can I avoid this?

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-neumann-9uzd3?file=/src/App.js)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([
    { name: "label1", value: 0 },
    { name: "label2", value: 0 },
    { name: "label3", value: 0 }
  ]);
  const handleChange = (name) => (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const updated = state.map((item) => {
      if (item.name === name) {
        return { name, value };
      }
      return item;
    });
    setState(updated);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const calculate = () => {
      const base1 = 99999;
      const base2 = 0.3;
      const base3 = 0.078;
      const val1 = base1 * base2;
      const val2 = val1 / base1;
      const val3 = val1 + (base1 - val1) * base3;
      const updated = [
        { name: "label1", value: val1 },
        { name: "label2", value: val2 },
        { name: "label3", value: val3 }
      ];
      // const updated2 = state.map((item, index) => updated[index]);
      // setState(updated)
    };
    calculate();
  }, [state]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.map(({ name, value }, index) => (
        <p key={index}>
          {name}: <input value={value} onChange={handleChange(name)} />
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just remove `state` in array dependencies because it will trigger useEffect when `state` change

```
useEffect(() => {
    const calculate = () => {
      const base1 = 99999;
      const base2 = 0.3;
      const base3 = 0.078;
      const val1 = base1 * base2;
      const val2 = val1 / base1;
      const val3 = val1 + (base1 - val1) * base3;
      const updated = [
        { name: "label1", value: val1 },
        { name: "label2", value: val2 },
        { name: "label3", value: val3 }
      ];
      setState(preState => preState.map((item, index) => updated[index]))
    };
    calculate();
  }, []);
```

Comment: the calculation will stop by typing if the dependency was removed

Comment: typing will call `handleChange`? So why need to call useEffect again?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to check if the new value is different from the current state before triggering the setState :

```
const updated2 = state.map((item, index) => updated[index]);
if(updated2 !== state) setState(updated)
```

You can also consider to do extract calculate() from the useEffect and call it in your handleChange